# How do I get the value of a multiple dynamically generated dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm doing a small website for school and I got stuck on this problem. How can I get the value of each dropdownlist? The dropdownlist are dynamically generated by code. I did the same with the textboxes and  it works perfectly, but with the values of the dropdownlists doesn't work, I mean, I don't get the values back. What should I do?

```
Partial Class Opties
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim aantalMensen As Integer = CInt(Session("aantalVolwassenen")) + CInt(Session("aantalKinderen")) + CInt(Session("aantalBabys"))
Session("aantalMensen") = CStr(aantalMensen)

For x As Integer = 1 To aantalMensen
  'Passagiers info
  Dim aanhef As New DropDownList()
  Dim aanhefSelectie As ListItem
  aanhefSelectie = New ListItem("Dhr.", "Dhr.")
  aanhef.Items.Add(aanhefSelectie)
  aanhefSelectie = New ListItem("Mevr.", "Mevr.")
  aanhef.Items.Add(aanhefSelectie)
  Dim voornaam As New TextBox With {.ID = "txtVoornaam" & x}
  Dim achternaam As New TextBox With {.ID = "txtAchternaam" & x}


  Dim lt As New Literal()
  Dim Endlt As New Literal()
  Dim space As New Literal()
  lt.Text = "<p>Persoon " + CStr(x) + ":"
  Endlt.Text = "</p> "
  space.Text = "<br />"

  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(lt)
  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(aanhef)
  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(voornaam)
  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(achternaam)
  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(Endlt)
  gegevensPassagiers.Controls.Add(space)
Next

For i As Integer = 1 To aantalMensen
  'Bagage DropDownlist
  Dim aantalKG As New DropDownList With {.ID = "ddlBagage" & i}
  Dim KGselectie As ListItem
  KGselectie = New ListItem("Geen", "Geen")
  aantalKG.Items.Add(KGselectie)
  KGselectie = New ListItem("15kg", "15kg")
  aantalKG.Items.Add(KGselectie)
  KGselectie = New ListItem("25kg", "25kg")
  aantalKG.Items.Add(KGselectie)
  KGselectie = New ListItem("35kg", "35kg")
  aantalKG.Items.Add(KGselectie)
  aantalKG.AutoPostBack = True

  Dim lt As New Literal()
  Dim Endlt As New Literal()
  Dim space As New Literal()
  lt.Text = "<p>Persoon " + CStr(i) + ":"
  Endlt.Text = "</p> "
  space.Text = "<br />"

  bagageDIV.Controls.Add(lt)
  bagageDIV.Controls.Add(aantalKG)
  bagageDIV.Controls.Add(Endlt)
  bagageDIV.Controls.Add(space)
Next
Dim index As Integer = 1
If IsPostBack Then
  For Each key As String In Request.Form.Keys
    If key.Contains("txtVoornaam") Then
      Session("Voornaam" & index) = CType(Request.Form(key), String)
      index += 1
    End If
    If key.Contains("txtFamilienaam") Then
      Session("Familienaam" & index) = CType(Request.Form(key), String)
      index += 1
    End If
    If key.Contains("ddlBagage") Then
      Session("Bagage" & index) = CType(Request.Form(key), String)
      index += 1
    End If
  Next

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: The first problem I see is that you will be reading all the items to your dropdown lists on every postback.  This will stop you from ever getting a value back from the page.

Comment: @MaCron So should I delete this "aantalKG.AutoPostBack = True"?

Comment: That would be up to you it depends on when you want to create these lists, if you only want to create them on initial page load then you need to put them in a postback = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after testing some methodes and attributes and other stuff.... I found an easy solution for my problem (also thanks for helping @MaCron).

Here is the code:

```
For Each aantalKG As DropDownList In bagageDIV.Controls.OfType(Of DropDownList)()
  Session("Bagage" & index) = aantalKG.SelectedValue
  index += 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for get selected value of dropdownlists.
for example:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("aanhef ");
var Selectedvalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```